# Java Scanner class reads one line and then stops

Tags: java

I have this problem with a method using the Scanner class. I am reading my text file with Scanner and then parse the int into an array.

```
public static void readItems() 
{
    try 
    {
        File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "./SsGame/item.dat");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        int line = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            String text = scanner.nextLine();
            text = text.replaceAll("\\W", "");
            System.out.println(text.trim());
            PlayerInstance.playerItems[line] = Integer.parseInt(text);
            line++;
        }
        scanner.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NumberFormatException e2)
    {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Heres the item.txt file:

```
1
1
2
3
4
```

I run the code and I get the following output:

```
1
```

I have tried using scanner.hasNextInt() and scaner.nextInt(); for this but then it won't print anything at all.

If I remove the parseInt part then the file will finish reading and all the numbers will be printed. Any ideas?

This the exception thrown:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at game.player.ReadPlayer.readItems(ReadPlayer.java:56)
at game.player.ReadPlayer.read(ReadPlayer.java:11)
at game.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:32)
at game.Frame.main(Frame.java:54)
```

Comment: Never have an empty catch block. It does more bad than good.

Comment: you're swallowing the exceptions - which you are probably getting for NumberFormatException

Comment: Print the exceptions when you catch them to see if they're getting thrown.

Comment: if your text file have data as "1 " then also it will enter in Parsing exception as it is will not able to convert to Integer. print stack trace in catch block

Comment: Thats the reason i have the replaceAll("\\W", "");

Answer (score 8):

I'm guessing `Integer.ParseInt()` is throwing an `NumberFormatException` because your line still contains the `\n`.

If you call `Integer.ParseInt(text.trim())` instead, it may fix it.

If you did your `Exception` handling properly, we would have a better idea.

Comment: @Mena They should handle all of their exceptions that are catching correctly, not just the one which is being thrown!

Comment: @Robadob true, but in this instance the problematic `catch` statement was the `NumberFormatException`. My edit was aimed at narrowing it down for the OP.

Comment: @Mena True, but you should have changed the first Exception not the second then, I'll do that now. Thanks

Comment: Got it working, added a check to see if the line was empty.

        if (text.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
    {
     continue;
    }

Comment: @LucasFrayBurchardt Just use `if (text.isEmpty()) {...}`.

Comment: If you got it working because of this answer make sure to upvote it/check it so people don't try to keep answering it

Answer (score 0):

This is because, you have a NumberFormatException, while parsing integer.

Add in catch section something like this

```
System.out.println(e.getCause());
```

And see, that you have an exception, that's why this code prints only first digit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful when you use the Scanner.

If you are reading more data, with Scaner like `input.nextInt();` then it will read only one int. **The carriage return isn't consumed** by `nextInt`. One solution is that add `input.nextLine();` so that it moves to the next line.

Other Solution is, which I prefer is to use **BufferedReader;**

```
    BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String tempStr = bufferRead.readLine();

    // Do some operation on tempStr
```

Hope this helps.